# Is $\mathcal{B}(H)$ complemented in $\ell_\infty(I, H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite diensional Hilbert space. Consider unit ball of $H$ as index set, denote it by $I$, then we have an isometric embedding
$$
j:\mathcal{B}(H)\to\ell_\infty(I,H):T\mapsto(T(i))_{i\in I}
$$
So we have a copy of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ in $\ell_\infty(I,H)$. Is **this** copy of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ complemented in $\ell_\infty(I,H)$?

I believe it is not, but I can't prove.

Comment: Norbert, by a psychological argument the answer should be *no* as otherwise it would give you a cheap proof of the Grothendieck property of $B(H)$. Also, it should then extend to $\ell_p$ proving the Grothendieck property of $B(\ell_p)$!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Grothendieck property. Btw I know that there is no contractive projection for my case.

Comment: This is one of my favourite problems in the *non-separable theory* (with applications to separable Banach spaces). Say that $Z$ is a *Grothendieck space* if every operator $T\colon Z\to c_0$ is weakly compact. Pfitzner proved that C*-algebras are G. if and only if they don't contain complemented copies of $c_0$. For instance, von Neumann algebras have this property. This answered an old question of Akemann. Since this property passes to quotients, complemented subspaces of G. spaces are G. It is easy to prove that $\ell_\infty(I, \ell_p)$ ($p\in (1,\infty)$) is G.

Comment: Well, even though this is an offtopic, why $B(H)$ have no complemented copies of $c_0$?

Comment: Because it is a dual space.

Comment: Ok, I got it, then $c_0$ would be complemented in $c_0^{**}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is **no**. No copy of $B(H)$ is complemented in $\ell_\infty(I, H)$. This is because the latter space is a Banach lattice and $B(H)$ lacks the local unconditional structure.

> Y. Gordon and D. R. Lewis, [Absolutely summing operators and local unconditional structures](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02392140#page-1), *Acta Mathematica*, **133** (1974), 27–48.

See also

> Y. Gordon and D. R. Lewis, [Banach ideals on Hilbert spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm54/sm54113.pdf), *Studia Mathematica*, **54** (1975), 161–172.

A Banach space $X$ has the local unconditional structure if and only if $X^{**}$ is complemented in a Banach lattice. (Consult [Theorem 17.5](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pHqyRSdgVTsC&lpg=PA348&ots=XCjCPgaZrg&dq=complemented%20subspaces%20of%20banach%20lattices%20local%20unconditional%20structure&hl=pl&pg=PA348#v=onepage&q=complemented%20subspaces%20of%20banach%20lattices%20local%20unconditional%20structure&f=false) in

> J. Diestel, H. Jarchow and A. Tonge, *[Absolutely Summing Operators](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pHqyRSdgVTsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Absolutely%20Summing%20Operators&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=vsDbVOirBoyR7Abl9IDQBA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Absolutely%20Summing%20Operators&f=false)*, Cambridge University Press, 1995.

for more details.)

Comment: I need some time to check all these refs

Comment: I now remember that I tried this approach to prove that $B(\ell_p)$ is Grothendieck but it didn't work as $B(\ell_p)$ doesn't have the LUST either.

Comment: Ok and one more question if don't mind. Do you know if unital non-commuative C*-algebras have LUST?

Comment: They certainly can have it: take sums of matrix algebras over abelian C*-algebras. However, non-type I C*-algebras don't have LUST.

Comment: Could you give a reference regarding non-type I C*-algebras?

Comment: Ah that's easy modulo known facts: a non-type I C*-algebra $A$ contains a non-type I nuclear C*-algebra $B$. Then $B^{**}$ is injective (hence complemented in $A^{**}$). So if $A$ has LUST, so does $B$. But an injective non-type I von Neumann algebras contain complemented subspaces isomorphic to $B(H)$ (this is essentially due to Kirchberg).

Comment: The correct notion of local structure for C*-algebras is the one coming from $M_n$ rather than finite-dimensional Banach lattices. This is very much related to nuclearity. You should look at papers by Junge *et. al* about $\mathscr{OLP}$-spaces.

Comment: Wish I could know all this. Thank you!

Comment: If you're interested there is a simpler proof for absence of lust for non-type I C^*-algebras: Any *-subalgebra $M_n$ in a $C^*$-algebra $A$ in contractively complemented. So lust constant of A is bounded below by lust constant of $M_n$. By results of Gordon and Lewis the latter tends to infinity for large $n$. So $A$ have lust iff it contains no big copies of $M_n$. Such $C^*$-algebras are called subhomogeneous.